# Adding div after each 4 loops

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

I need to add a div tag after each 5 images, so the html markup should be something like this:

```
<div>
      <img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/143/321464099_a7cfcb95cf_t.jpg" />
      <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3089/2796719087_c3ee89a730_t.jpg" />
      <img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/79/244441862_08ec9b6b49_t.jpg" />
      <img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/28/66523124_b468cf4978_t.jpg" />

</div>
<div>

      <img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/163/399223609_db47d35b7c_t.jpg" />
      <img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/135/321464104_c010dbf34c_t.jpg" />
      <img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/40/117346184_9760f3aabc_t.jpg" />
      <img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/153/399232237_6928a527c1_t.jpg" />
    </div>
<div>

      <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3629/3323896446_3b87a8bf75_t.jpg" />
      <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3023/3323897466_e61624f6de_t.jpg" />
      <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3650/3323058611_d35c894fab_t.jpg" />
      <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3635/3323893254_3183671257_t.jpg" />
    </div>
```

I have to use foreach loop thats the requirement , apart from that i can use any control statement , can any one provide any assistance with this logic, i have tried something like this with no succes , the maximum images are 100 , thats why i initialise an int to 100

```
 foreach (var page in images)
 {
    int b = 100 ;
    for (int a = 0 ; a = b ; a++)
    {
        <div><img src="page.name" alt="page.alt" /> </div>
    }
 }
```

Comment: Why not check `a % 4 == 0` and print the div when it is true?

Comment: Why cant you use a Repeater with the div and the 4 images?

Comment: Wish i can ,foreach loop is the requirement for the work, I can integrate other loops within foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something along these lines should get you going in the right direction

```
foreach (var page in images)
 {
    int b = 100 ;
    bool first=true;
    bool wroteDivEnd = false;
    for (int a = 0 ; a = b ; a++)
    {
        wroteDivEnd=false;
        if (a% 4==0)
        {
           if (!first)
           { 
              // as long as this is not the first time we have written a 
              //start div, then we need to write and end one
              //write previous div end </div>
              wroteDivEnd=true;
           }
           //write new div start <div>
           //set the flag so we know we have written the first start div
           first=false;
        }
        // write out the images
        <img src="page.name" alt="page.alt" /> 

    }
    //make sure your last </div> is written
    if(!wroteDivEnd)
    { 
     //write out the final missing </div>
    }
 }
```

Comment: looks ok , but the issue is , if i got like 100 images which makes the set of 100/4 = 25 div tags , but what if i have 99 images , thats makes a set of 24 , so the remaining 3 images should be left , but i want that 3 images also in div , so the priority is 4 but if there are 3 then wrap that 3 images in div

Comment: @MrA thats what this bit is meant to mean -> `//make sure your last </div> is written`  do we have to solve everything for you?  anyway added an edit showing how you might do this...

Answer (score 1):

You can count your rows, and add `<div>` when the count is divisible by four:

```
var count = 0;
foreach (var row in myData) {
    // Open before rows 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, and so on
    if (count%4 == 0) {
        // Add <div>
    }
    // Write the line
    // Close after rows 3, 7, 11, 15, and so on
    if (count%4 == 3) {
        // Add </div>
    }
}
// Don't forget the closing row in case the number of images
// is not divisible by four
if (count%4 != 3) {
    // Add </div>
}
```

Comment: looks ok , but the issue is , if i got like 100 images which makes the set of 100/4 = 25 div tags , but what if i have 99 images , thats makes a set of 24 , so the remaining 3 images should be left , but i want that 3 images also in div , so the priority is 4 but if there are 3 then wrap that 3 images in div

Comment: @MrA That's what the last `if` is for!

Comment: @MrA thats what the bit at the end is for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var imagesInDiv = 4;
var maxItems = 100;
for (var i = 0; i < images.Length && i < maxItems; ++i)
{
    if (i % imagesInDiv == 0)
    {
        <div>
    }

    <img src="@images[i].name" alt="@images[i].alt" />

    // if this is the last image in a set OR last image that you have OR last image allowed
    if (i % imagesInDiv == imagesInDiv - 1 || i == images.Length - 1 || i == maxItems - 1)
    {
        </div>
    }
}
```

Edit 1: I added some comments

Answer (score 0):

```
string finalstring = "";
foreach (var page in images)
{
   for (int a = 0 ; a < 100 ; a++)
   {
      if (a % 4 != 0)
         str += <img src="page.name" alt="page.alt" />;  
      else
      {
         str = "<div>" + str + "</div>";
         finalstring += str;  
         str = "";
      }
   }
}
```